# How to show WooCommerce Categories on 'shop' page instead of products?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

### Setup

I am running:

- WordPress 5.4.1
- WooCommerce 4.1.1

I am writing a custom theme that overrides some of the WooCommerce templates by placing my own templates in: **themes/my_theme/woocommerce/template-name.php**

I have established that the shop page (home) uses **archive-product.php** and have successfully copied the one from **plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php** to my theme and made some minor HTML changes which work fine. There are no functional changes in my theme's copy, just some HTML.

### Problem

There is an option to set the shop page to show categories instead of products:

**Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Catalogue**

Shop page display is now set to **Show Categories**

[image]

However the shop homepage seems to ignore this setting entirely. It seems odd that WooCommerce's *own template* does not honour this setting!

How do I find this setting and then show the categories (as thumbnails) on the shop homepage?

---

*As a side note, the Storefront theme does honour the setting but they do not have the template **archive-product.php**. Everything in Storefront is highly obfuscated and after much debugging of it / trying to take it apart I cannot discover which template file it is using for the shop page.*

Comment: The template you're using is specifically made to showcase products, so I don't think it'll check that setting. Can you show a screenshot of the storefront theme page that does work with that setting?

Comment: I don’t have it to hand (as on mobile) but it literally replaces product thumbnails with category thumbnails. Why include a setting that doesn’t work with the templates that Woocommerce uses out of the box? Is Woocommerce making an assumption we’re using Storefront?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workable solution. The WooCommerce default templates don't support the setting to show categories on the Shop page.

However using a shortcode with `do_shortcode()`, and a condition this can be achieved as follows:

```
if (is_shop()) {

  echo do_shortcode('[product_categories hide_empty="0"]');

} else {

  woocommerce_product_loop_start();

  if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();

      /**
      * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
      */
      do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

      wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }

  }

  woocommerce_product_loop_end();
}
```

Still:

- I would like to know how to pick up the 'show categories' customisation setting shown in the question, so my theme responds to that.
- Is there a better way than using `do_shortcode()`, this feels like a bit of a hack